# How does VQE performs the measurement on a given Hamiltonian?

Tags: qiskit, hamiltonian-simulation, vqe

I'm trying to understand, given a specific Hamiltonian, for example $H = Z\otimes Z+X\otimes Z$, does the VQE algorithm calculates the expectation value of $Z\otimes Z$ first or does it calculates the expectation value of $X\otimes Z$ first? couldn't understand it from the source code.

Thank you very much!

Comment: If you use IBM hardware, you can look at the order of the circuit being executed on the hardware and see which one is being executed first.

Comment: I see you found your answer, but why would matter though which one it measure first?

Answer (score 1):

For a VQE, the circuit applies $Z \otimes Z$ and $X \otimes Z$ on different iterations, and their expectation values are added classically. So, it doesn't really matter which is run first on a quantum computer - they're entirely different circuits.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answers. After a check it appears that the VQE algorithm processes first the rightmost expression and only then the leftmost. i.e. it first processes $X\otimes Z$ and then $Z\otimes Z$